# Split PHP Variable in to array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this string:

```
ckb=199&ckb=232&ckb=200&ckb=233&ckb=201&ckb=234..
```

I need to create an array from it:

```
[0] => 199
[1] => 232
[2] => 200
[3] => 233
[4] => 201
[5] => 234
```

how can i do this with php?

Comment: _how to slipt fucation in php?_ - how to what?

Comment: that's a string, not a function, dear Mohamed. check http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: i need this value (199 and 232,200,201,234.)will be array store

Comment: If this is coming from a URL, have you tried [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: It would be much easier to parse this string if you changed it to ckb[]=199&ckb[]=232&ckb[]=200&ckb[]=233&ckb[]=201&ckb[]=234 . Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex solution:

```
<?php 
    $str = "ckb=199&ckb=232&ckb=200&ckb=233&ckb=201&ckb=234";
    preg_match_all("/=([^&]+|.*$)/", $str, $matches); 
    print_r($matches[1]); 
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 199
    [1] => 232
    [2] => 200
    [3] => 233
    [4] => 201
    [5] => 234
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse_str` to parse a query string. however it expects php's style of array syntax( `key[]=val` ) so you will need to add the square brackets:

```
$str = 'ckb=199&ckb=232&ckb=200&ckb=233&ckb=201&ckb=234';
$str = str_replace('=','[]=',$str);
parse_str($str, $output);
$final = $output['ckb'];
var_dump($final);
```

Comment: i like this answer too, just my voting is exhausted

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is the use `explode()` here: Example:

```
$string = 'ckb=199&ckb=232&ckb=200&ckb=233&ckb=201&ckb=234';
$pieces = array_map(function($piece){
    $sub_piece =  explode('=', $piece);
    return array_pop($sub_piece);
}, explode('&', $string));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($pieces);
```

Should output something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 199
    [1] => 232
    [2] => 200
    [3] => 233
    [4] => 201
    [5] => 234
)
```

Sidenote: Somewhat a URL from the looks of it. If you want to modify the string, alternatively, you could also use `parse_str` and make it an array instead.